# Efficient way to calculate A^B mod C, where B is high number

Tags: modular-arithmetic, modules, cryptography

After reading [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)
, I know how to calculate *certain* (easy to express with in binary) exponents. 
However, I find this method inefficient to calculate on paper.

I have this following problem:
**2 ^ 2000002 mod 41**

What would be a "*good*" (efficient, quick, simple) way to approach and solve this type of problems, where the exponent is a very large number?

Comment: Fermat's little theorem?

Comment: Note: that particular problem can be solved mentally since $2000002 \equiv 2\pmod {40}$ (visibly).

Comment: See [modular order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242).